# Continuity property of probabilities.

Tags: probability-theory

> Consider a probabilistic model whose sample space is the real
>    line. Show that      $\mathrm{\mathbf{P}}\left ( \left [  0, \infty 
>  \right ) \right ) = \lim_{n \to \infty }\mathrm{\mathbf{P}}\left (
>  \left [  0, n  \right ] \right )$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty
>  }\mathrm{\mathbf{P}}\left ( \left [ n, \infty  \right ) \right ) = 0.$

Could anybody give me a hint on how to approach the above problem?
Kindly *do not* solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: 
$$[0,\infty)=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}[0,n]$$
and this is an increasing sequence of measurable sets.

You also have:
$$\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb{N}}[n,\infty)=\emptyset$$
and this is a decreasing sequence of measurables sets.

You also have standard properties of measure (sequential continuity)...